How to render numpy docstring nicely in VSCode?
I am working on a Python utilities library for parsing output generated by an external simulation program we use (called MESA, but it's not important for this question).
I plan to use the library mainly for myself, but it's very likely that I will share it with my friends who also use this program to run simulations. In the future I might even publish this library for anyone who needs to parse MESA output.
Both for my sake, and also for my friends who are less experienced in Python, I want to document the tools I write. I like the numpy docstring style so I decided to go with that. I base my docstrings on the style guide I linked above and based on this example from the sphinx napoleon extension which looks complete.
For example, I have this function and its docstring:
"""Utilities for reading and processing MESA output files."""

__all__ = [
    "PathLike",
    "read_history",
]

import os

import pandas as pd
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.table import QTable

PathLike = os.PathLike | str | bytes


def read_history(
    path: PathLike = "history.data",
    units: dict[str, u.Unit] | None = None,
    descriptions: dict[str, str] | None = None,
    *,
    meta_start: int = 1,
    data_start: int = 4,
) -> QTable:
    """Read a MESA history file and return it as an astropy `QTable`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    path
        Path to the history file (defaults to "history.data").
    units
        Optional dictionary with units to apply to columns. For example,
        if the history file has columns named "star_age" and "star_mass", and you want
        to assign them units of years and solar masses, respectively, you can pass
        you can pass `units={"star_age": u.yr, "star_mass": u.Msun}`. The returned table
        will have the corresponding units applied to the columns.
    descriptions
        Optional dictionary with descriptions to apply to columns.
    meta_start
        Indicates the line number where the metadata of the history file starts.
        Only non-blank and non-comment lines are considered. Starts from zero.
        Defaults to 1 as that is usually where the metadata is located in MESA
        history files (Usually the first line, line 0, is column numbers and then the
        second line, line 1, is column names).
    data_headers_start
        Indicates the line number where the data of the history file starts.
        Only non-blank and non-comment lines are considered. Starts from zero.
        Defaults to 4 as that is usually where the data is located in MESA
        history files (Usually the first 3 lines are, lines 0 to 2, are for metadata.
        The 4th line, is blank so it doesn't count, and the 5th line, line 3, contains
        column numbers so the data columns names are at the 6th line which is line 4).

    Returns
    -------
    QTable
        An astropy `QTable` with the data from the history file. The history's metadata
        is stored in the `meta` attribute of the table under the key "history_meta"
        (The `meta` attribute can contain more information, including user custom
        information).

    """
    ...

This example looks good to me and it seems to follow the numpy docstring style guide. I work with VSCode and when I hover the function to look at the generated docs, it doesn't look very good:

It looks cluttered and messy. I think I followed the style guide correctly, so I guess that VSCode simply doesn't render numpy's style guide very good (If I am not wrong, VSCode simply renders markdown).
Is there a way to make the documentation look good and readable in VSCode? Right now, I mainly use the library for myself, and I'll probably share it with my friends so I don't want to use a full blown documentation generator like sphinx (although I probably will in the future if I publish the library). On the other hand, I don't want to write the docs in markdown which might render well in VSCode, but doesn't comply to any standard docstring style. I just want to document my code, such that the docstring is readable and the IDE (VSCode) is able to show me the docs nicely.

Have you tried making your params description a list ? (prepending the items name with markdown bullets (- my_param) ?
Right now your docstring is mostly text with headers, hence the indentation problems..

I want to stick to the numpy docstring style. Look at the links in my question. The style doesn't use markdown bullets.

VSCode support numpy docstrings when hovering on the functions instead of in the editor.Do you have a list of installed extensions for the VSCode?

Which extension do I need?

I believe you need to remove some plugins and update VSCode to the newest version as I was unable to reproduce the rendering issue in the editor.The hovering docstring looks good for me.

Which plugins could make the documentation look bad in VSCode? I have the newest version.

By default, VSCode will not render the docstring in IDE but showing detailed documentation when you hovering on a function(which is compliant to the Numpy Docstring standard).According to your screenshot there may be some extension installed and they made your editor like this.As I don't have the list of what extension you have installed,I suggest a clean install with only Python extension pack.
